# estimating battery discharge current approximately from ac load current

Tags: power, batteries, load, dc-ac

I would like to know that if we have a data logger installed at a site and the logger measured the constant load current of 10 A from the Grid(Single phase@ 230 v) during a certain time say 10 am.

> Now my question is if i **replaced the grid** **with a battery back up s/m**
>   (for eg: say 48 v 150 AH Battery and a DC to AC converter System) what
>   would be the battery discharge current from the battery for the time
>   10 am.?

Considering the absence of grid here what will be the approximate current drawn from the battery to match the out put current of 10A @ 230V for the DC-AC converter.
And what all factors should we consider before approximating the battery discharge current

I would appreciate your valuable inputs

Answer (score 3):

A good first approximation would be to:

1. Calculate the apparent power in VA.  That's easy, just take the RMS voltage times the RMS current, in your case 10A * 230V.
2. Divide that power by the battery voltage to get the battery current.  Note that this assumes a perfect converter, which doesn't exist; remember, this is a first approximation.
3. According to your question, you're done, but you may also be interested in maximum runtime.  For that, divide the battery's capacity (150 amp-hours in your case) by the current that you got in step #2.

Okay, now that you have an unacheivable maximum performance figure, you can start accounting for inefficiencies, specifically:

- The converter isn't 100% efficient.  Perhaps more like 80-90%.  The other 10-20% represents extra current pulled from the battery and converted to heat.
- Battery capacity is not constant with load.  It tends to decrease under heavy loads so that you may get 170-200 AH under a light load and closer to 100 AH under a heavy load.  Exactly how much it changes depends on the specific battery.